# How do I set a postgresql password in pgpass.conf for the Administrator account on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, postgresql

I have a pgpass.conf file that works well for my default user. It is in `C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Roaming/postgresql/pgpass.conf`. It reads like so;

```
localhost:5432:*:postgres:password1
```

I have a process that runs under the Administrator account. When I run `whoami` under this process I get `nt authority/system`. I want to be able to access the database from this process but it gets stuck because it needs a password. I have tried putting the above pgpass.conf into `C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/postgresql/pgpass.conf` and `C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Roaming/postgresql/pgpass.conf` but it does not work. Is this the correct place for this file? Am I even able to do this as the Administrator. Unfortunately I cannot change the user that this process runs under.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See what `echo %APPDATA%` outputs when you're logged with this account.

As an alternative, you can point the `PGPASSFILE` environment variable to the location of the file, wherever it it, or even set the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable with the password itself to avoid that file altogether.

The [Environment Variables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-envars.html) and [The Password File](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-pgpass.html) sections from the doc give the details.

Comment: Beautiful thankyou. I couldn't face trying to configure my process to run that echo command so went with the PGPASSFILE option. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody will use PowerShell then use: `$env:APPDATA`. This will uncover AppData folder in Windows Server 2016 for MS SQL Server 2017 Agent Job with PowerShell subsystem (Type) like this: `C:\Users\SQLSERVERAGENT\AppData\Roaming` where `\postgresql` folder needs to be created and `pgpass.conf` file copied from user location.